# firebase_core:1.20.0,Flutter iOS build error

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to build for iOS. I updated to flutter version 3.0.2, and firebase_core:1.20.0
I am encountering this error

`/Users/Drive/Flutter/Project/vepaar/whatshash-mobile-app/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:110:14: Value of optional type 'HeartbeatsBundle?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'makeHeartbeatsPayload' of wrapped base type 'HeartbeatsBundle'`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue... I just followed a tip from kenethj on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9960#issuecomment-1183371858.

Just change the SWIFT_VERSION to 5.3 in Podfile. Works for me.